# Java POST HTTPsUrlConnection returns 200 response

Tags: java, forms, http-post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to post some login data to a form in order to grab the cookies from the response.
The url is: https://www.deviantart.com/users/login

However I can not get the server to return FOUND 302 but only 200, so I think I'm b0rking my querystring or headers in some manner:

```
try {
        String query = URLEncoder.encode("&username="+user+"&password="+password+"&remember_me=1", "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL("https://www.deviantart.com/users/login");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        HttpsURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.deviantart.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla 4.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), false);
        out.write(query);
        out.flush();
```

Comment: Are you sure a POST to https://www.deviantart.com/users/login with valid username and password returns a 302 and not 200 OK? I tried logging in using a browser and I notice the response is 200 OK and not 302.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, its normal to get response "200", means that your request was recognized and properly answered.

But when I need to know about HTTP code responses and some details I usually use this link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

A 302 response is a redirect ... telling the browser to go to another page.  A sites login page will often do this to send the user to a "login succeeded" page, or back to the home page or the page that the user was originally looking at.  But it doesn't have to.

A 200 response means "Succeeded", and for a POST request will result in the browser staying at the login page.

I'd not worry about getting a 200 instead of a 302.  If you are sending requests from a Java app, you probably don't care where the site redirects you after login.  The thing that matters is whether your credentials have been accepted, and you can only determine that by trying a request that needs authentication.  (You need to make sure that your code captures the cookies set by the response to your login POST.  They need to be supplied in follow-on requests.)

If you are worried that you have "borked" the login URL query String, fetch the login page and look at its source to see if there are any hidden inputs in the form.